# Intellij Idea: Exclude packages from navigate class

Tags: intellij-idea

When "navigating" to a class "Navigate -> Class" and entering e.g. "Regexp" I am offered a multitude of classes from "sun.misc" or "com.sun" which I do not (never) want to navigate to. Is it possible to filter the Navigation by package name?

I know, how to do it for completion, but not for Navigation.